# Working with unobtrusive AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm currently working on a ToDo List for a college project, and I'd like to take on some AJAX, but I'd also like to make it work both ways (pure PHP and also with AJAX, if JavaScript's available).

On my PHP approach, I use some HTML code embeded (like **`<td>$value</td>`).** On AJAX, I guess I would strip the HTML from the PHP file, take the printing results part away, and I would just add it to the JavaScript (with jQuery) code, but that would render the *pure* PHP approach unusable.

With the AJAX examples I've seen, the PHP file that processes the data can no longer *work* stand-alone, and would not produce any human-friendly results if weren't for the AJAX side. So my question is: do you know of a working example of an AJAX and PHP approach together, or could you provide one, please?

I hope I made myself clear, since I'm not a native english speaker. In case you need clarification, please let me know.

Comment: I think it's been my mistake when asking, because your answers aren't what I'm looking for. I tried to mix two questions, and there lies the problem. Anyways, I'm really just looking for suggestions on how to make a Web application work with both alternatives: PHP-only, and AJAX. First, as if the user didn't have JavaScript at all, and second, if it does have JavaScript fully enabled. Thanks, and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using 'smart' php requests where the output is dependent on the parameters passed to PHP.

to get data as a webpage, just make a request to the php file `index.php`

but to get data as json, make the same request using a query string `index.php?type=JSON`

Your php will have to have a bit more logic behind it, but it allows you to request the same information from the same place in a different format. This also would allow you to expand formats to include RSS, PDF(if you've got the file available), or anything else.

Comment: This is kind of logic I was asking for, yes. Something that could be available for people with, and without JavaScript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't need to strip the HTML.

You can use the jQuery load function.

The load functions allows you to search within the result.
So if you would like to load the table of page 2 with ajax you could write:

```
$("#myTableContainer").load("mypage.php?page=2 #myTable");
```

This might replace the page 1 table with the page 2 table.

Take a look at the footer navigation example on http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Using thee following directly from [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Your php callback can be something as simple as:

```
<?php

  header('Content-Type: text/plain');
  echo "Hello World";

?>
```

Though I recommended taking a very close look at [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  for any AJAX needs.